# Proof that the second condition of equilibrium is equivalent to no rotation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, torque, equilibrium

I'm currently working my way through an introductory mechanics course, using University Physics with Modern Physics by Young and Freedman.

I understand that the first condition for equilibrium, i.e. $\sum \pmb{F} = \mathbf{0}$, ensures that the center of mass of the rigid body in question not accelerate.

What I *don't* understand is how the second condition of equilibrium, that the net torque $\sum \pmb{\tau}$ with respect to a point $O$ be zero, implies that the rigid body is not rotating around about $O$ (by "rotating about $O$", I assume my textbook really means rotating about some *axis* through $O$ - is this correct?). Perhaps it doesn't, but this is what I intuitively feel like we are trying to accomplish with the second condition of equilibrium.

The textbook goes on to claim that if a rigid body is not rotating about $O$, then its angular momentum with respect to $O$ is zero. Furthermore, since the rate of change of this angular momentum is given by $\sum \pmb{\tau}$, letting the latter be equal to zero ensures that the rigid body continues to not rotate about $O$, the authors argue.

Could somebody please provide me with a proof of why the second condition of equilibrium is equivalent to the body not rotating about any point, if this is so? If not - exaplain what the second condition of equilibrium *does* accomplish.

I hope my question is clear - if not, tell me, and I will try to clarify.

Comment: The actual text in the book (equation 11.2) says: "for a nonrotating object to stay nonrotating" as the significance of the net torque being zero. Where did you get this interpretation from? What edition of the text are you using?

Comment: You are right @nasu, my it doesn't say that. I will clarify this in an edit.

Answer (score 1):

## First, recheck the textbook. Are you * sure * you read and quoted it correctly?  It sounds like perhaps you misread. See comments below.

That said, lets answer the question as asked....

**Something's wrong with these statements as asked and quoted....**

> $\sum \pmb{F} = \mathbf{0}$, ensures that the center of mass of the rigid body in question not accelerate.

**Correct**. For a rigid body and in a classroom context, no net force, means no net acceleration. It means whatever velocity it has, it keeps *("objects in motion stay in motion unless acted on by a force")*. That's worth saying explicitly, given your question....

> $\sum \pmb{\tau}$ with respect to a point $O$ [being] zero, implies that the rigid body is not rotating around about $O$

**Incorrect**. Torque is the rotational "equivalent" of a force, in simple terms. This would be like saying that if there is no net force, an object has no velocity. Whereas what it has, is no net **acceleration** (again in a simple classroom sense).

What it should say is, net torque $\sum \pmb{\tau}$ with respect to a point $O$ being zero, implies that the rigid body has no net **angular acceleration** around $O$. (In a simple classroom sense). As with linear forces, it can certainly have an angular *velocity*.

And yes, that means "around any axis through $O\$", as you surmise.

> The textbook goes on to claim that if a rigid body is not rotating about $O$, then its angular momentum with respect to $O$ is zero.

**Correct**. If it's not rotating around $O$, then it has zero angular velocity (hence also angular momentum) around $O$. Note that this **doesn't** mean there is no net torque. For example if a flywheel spins clockwise, and you constantly apply a counterclockwise torque, it will instantaneously have zero angular velocity and momentum before starting to spin counterclockwise. That's the same as applying a constant linear force to an object that changes velocity from +ve to -ve.

> Since the rate of change of this angular momentum is given by $\sum \pmb{\tau}$, letting the latter be equal to zero ensures that the rigid body continues to not rotate about $O$ *[= zero angular velocity]*, the authors argue.

**Incorrect**. If the rate of change (of **anything**!!) is zero, that doesn't mean the thing itself is zero. Basic calculus 101. If net force is zero, it doesn't "ensure" an object has zero velocity. If net torque is zero, it doesn't "ensure" an object has zero angular velocity. End of.

Put another way, using their own words, *"since the rate of change of this angular momentum is given by $\sum \pmb{\tau}$, letting the latter be equal to zero"* ..... If you set the rate of change of angular momentum to zero, then by definition *the angular momentum doesn't change*. So it's constant. But nothing at all says it has to be constant *and zero*. Could be constant and any value.

## Bottom line.....

> Could somebody please provide me with a proof of why the second condition of equilibrium is equivalent to the body not rotating about any point?

If quoted accurately, your textbook authors sound like they need to get better technical proofreaders before their next textbook. But honestly, it sounds like you just misread it or didn't read it as written. It happens.

What's good is, you had the instinct in the topic, to realise that what you **thought** you read, sounded wrong. And indeed it was.

Don't sweat it, sounds like you understand it just fine.

Comment: The text does not say this.  The OP should provide the actual statement from thebook and not his "interpretation".

Comment: That's possible. And from your brevity, I assume you know the textbook and don't just have the OP's question to go on. I think this is still valuable because whatever the book says, the OP states this confuses them, and we can clarify. Perhaps "check you read the text carefully" is a second point, I've now added that up top, but the fact they are confused on this is still the basis of their question.

Comment: Yes, I am using this book for the introductory physics course I am teaching and I checked with the text before I wrote my comments, of course.

Comment: Thought so, thank you for confirming.  Hopefully the explanation will be of use anyhow.

Comment: Sure, as the OP question show, the equilibrium conditions need some details. It is not uncommon to state the conditions of equilibrium without qualification.

Comment: Thank you, Stilez. It's hard to respond to all of your feedback in one single comment. I agree on you that rate of change of the angular momentum being 0 does not imply that entity itself is 0. However, I assumed earlier on in the same paragraph that the linear momentum about O was zero to begin with. My greatest concern right now is this: I do not get why a body which isn't rotating about O necessarily has zero angular momentum about O. That they definitely do claim in the book.

Comment: A spaceship unaffected by any external forces, which is traveling in a straight line with constant velocity v in outer space, surely has an angular momentum about any point to the left of it, for example. But I wouldn't say it's rotating about that point.

Comment: But it actually is.  Say your spaceship is currently at (1,0), and moving in a straight line at (0,1) units/second. Exactly like you describe, let's pick (0,0) as our point on the "left".  We now have exactly what you describe. It moves from (1,0)->(1,1)->(1,2).  But another way to describe its movement is, it moves around the point simultaneously changing distance. (0 degrees, dist=1)->(45 degrees, dist=1.414)->(63.4 degrees, dist=2.24)

Comment: You have to be really careful with saying an object has one fixed value for angular and rotation related stuff (momentum,velocity, acceleration, also moment of inertia when you come to that in class). The values can and do change if you change the axis you measure them around. And also, the frame itself (the coordinate grid you refer back to) may be rotating too, which will cause some subtle issues that most students have to think hard to understand. You aren't there yet in class, sounds like, but you're touching on something thats easy to trip on, when you first meet it.

Comment: The answer is, if we decide where to measure rotation around - your point "O" or the axis - and we find the object is not rotating ***around that axis***, then it doesn't have angular momentum **about that specific axis**. It could still be rotating with respect to **some other axis**, and have angular momentum with respect to **that other axis**, however.

Comment: I don't know if you have hit force diagrams and moments yet, but when you do,you'll find we often take moments (measure the turning forces) around **multiple points**, not just one. Precisely because the turning forces vary depending what point you measure them around (your chosen axis). But as its stationary/equilibrium, meaning **nothing is turning around any point in the diagram** so we can say **the net moment (turning force) around every one of several points are zero**, and get extra equations to eliminate the variables that way. If you haven't hit that yet, you will :) have a heads up!

Comment: All right, thanks for explaining. I'm still not sure I get it, but I'll keep working problems and refer back to your answers every now and then, and hopefully it'll dawn on me. I'm doing the course on my own and I *have* covered everything included in the course, so I'm fairly comfortable with moment of inertia, angular momentum, free body diagrams etc. One thing that the book mentions at the beginning of the chapter on rotational motion is that the path of a rigid body can always be described as translation of the center of mass and rotation about some axis through the center of mass.

Comment: But that it's beyond the scope of the book to prove it. I have a feeling my questions can all be traced back to that theorem.

Comment: That's going to be the **instantaneous** path, not its path in general. Essentially says that just like you can resolve a force like say friction into (say) 2 forces which are components parallel plus normal (perpendicular) at any instant, you can always resolve a particle or rigid objects motion at any instant into 2 more general components - a pure translation plus a pure rotation - at any instant. ......

Comment: ....... The phrase "around the centre of mass" is there to make sure it * is * a pure rotation, that you don't accidentally absorb some linear velocity/momentum of the body as a whole, into your rotation component, by your choice of axis.  The translation doesn't need that phrase **as far as I know**, only the rotation does. Translation component will be the same wherever measured.  Proof probably is a bit beyond the coursework, but you might well understand if you Google or ask.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133007/discussion-between-simon-smn-and-stilez).